# How can you pass in a local Maven m2 to Gradle as a property?

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, gradle

I am currently trying to build my Android app through a Jenkins Freestyle project. I am able to build it in Android Studio successfully, but Jenkins is not able to find a dependency (that I know is installed on my machine in my .m2). Is there a way I can pass my .m2 folder into the Gradle system or project properties so it knows to search there?

My goal is to be able to do this without editing my build.gradle file directly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the repositories - you will need to modify the build.xml

`mavenLocal()` - provides access to local .m2 - but not advised see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local

you can conditionally add mavenLocal() and control the flag from command line

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you are running Jenkins on your local system, otherwise I do not know how it should be possible to get a dependency from the local Maven cache of your workstation.

If you do not want to change your `build.gradle` file, it is possible to register a system-specific initialization script. It needs to be placed inside `~/.gradle/init.d` and should contain something like the following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() 
    } 
}
```